# Flex Encryption Secret Value

Tags: apache-flex, encryption, flash

So I know it is possible to decompile SWF files. I know it produces the ActionScript contained in the file. Is there any way to store a value in a Flex application that can be reliably assumed to be secret? I am very new to Flex and am just curious.

I need to preform some type of hashing in my Flex app in order to ensure the request came from the Flex app and not from the clients web browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

If a calculation is performed on the client side, then all the data necessary to do that calculation is available to the client, and so the calculation can in principle be done by any client software.

Comment: I was afraid that would be the answer :\